# Javascript not treating buttons in loop individually

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I have a loop that that retrieves rows from the db and spits it out in a table. For every row I have a button that is generated. So if I have 5 rows, 5 buttons appear. Currently when I press the first button, the function does what it's supposed to do which is hides the button and the puts "Button Pressed". The issue I am having is Ok, I pressed the first button, now I need to press the second button. When I press the second button, it hides the button and doesn't put any text. Also, if I press the second button first, it hides the button on the first AND second button and what used to be the first button now says "Button Pressed" when it wasn't really pressed. I want it where each button works individually. Is that possible?

```
function buttonpressed(button) {
   button.style.visibility = "hidden";
   document.getElementById("ChangeButton1").innerHTML="Button Pressed";
   window.open ('test2.html','newWin', 'width=400,height=400');
}


while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{
echo '
<tr>
<td class="td" valign="top"><p id="ChangeButton"><input type="submit" name="buttonpressed" value="buttonpressed" onclick="SendEmail(this); return false;"></p></td>
</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicate IDs.

Instead, remove the `id="ChangeButton"` from the HTML, and change your JS to:

```
button.parentNode.innerHTML = "Button Pressed";
window.open(...);
```